# How to use CanCan on non-RESTful action while examining POST params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a sort action on a model called Chain. Following the sort example in [Railscasts #147 Sortable Lists](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised), the action is passed a :chain param that is an array of Chain ids:

```
def sort
  params[:chain].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Chain.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})
  end
  ....
end
```

How can I use CanCan to make sure that the user has permission to update each of the individual chains that are in the params?

My :update Chain ability depends on whether the user has an admin role in the "Space" to which a chain belongs. Here's the definition:

```
can :update, Chain do |chain|
  user.memberships.detect{|m| m.space == chain.space}.role.admin?
end
```

I'd like to see both the controller code and the Ability.rb code.

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
class Ability
      include CanCan::Ability

      permitted_ids = Store.all.map &:id #you can store this in a db or whatever

      def initialize(user)
         permitted_ids.each do |i| #simply the can method has to run evaluate the Chain model against all your ids
           can :update, Chain, id: i  
         end
      end

end
```

Controller

```
def sort
  params[:chain].each_with_index do |id, index|
    authorize! :update, Chain, id: id
    Chain.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})
  end
end
```

Comment: The :update Chain ability is conditional on the chain (the user has to belong to a Workspace to which the chain also belongs). So how do I check in the controller if the user has :update privilege on each of the chains being passed?

Comment: I think for this to work I would need to know the permitted_ids ahead of time, and that's not the case. See my edit for how the :update Chain permission is defined.